# Как заменить строку #listen_addresses = 'localhost' на строку listen_addresses = '*' используя sed в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sed

Пробую команду:

```
sed "s/#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'" /somefile
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что `\*` или `\\\*`

Comment: Ну так а где третий слеш?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, точно) А этого хватит?

Comment: не совсем вас понимаю, куда слэш необходимо добавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://pastebin.com/RKjJxsR6

Comment: `sed "s/#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/" /somefile` в конец выражения

Comment: к сожалению команда sed "s/#listen_addresses = 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/" не изменяет строку

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

target="localhost"
replacement="'*'"

perl -wE'
    BEGIN { $p = shift; $r = shift }; 
    $_=q(#listen_addresses = 'localhost'); s/\Q$p/$r/; say
' "$target" "$replacement"
```

Выведет:

> #listen_addresses = '*'

Perl Oneline:

```
perl -wE 'BEGIN { $p = shift; $r = shift }; $_=q(#listen_addresses = localhost); s/\Q$p/$r/; print' "localhost" "'*'"
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059656/how-to-search-replace-arbitrary-literal-strings-in-sed-and-awk-and-perl).

Comment: интересно, но как это сделать используя sed ))

Answer (score 0):

Правильная команда:

```
sed -i "/listen/s/\#listen_addresses\ =\ 'localhost'/listen_addresses = '*'/g" /somefile
```